# RAID array shared between Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: mount, raid

I am booting both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 off their own dedicated SSDs. No problem.

I have 3 2TB HDDs I would like to run in a RAID5 array which I can **share between both operating systems.**

I have configured the RAID array via the Legacy RAID ROM utility of my Gigabyte Z97-HD3 motherboard.

Ubuntu identifies a 4.0TB Block device, which I have formatted in NTFS.

However attempting to mount the device results in the following error:

```
Error mounting /dev/dm-2 at /media/daniel/data: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/dm-2" "/media/daniel/data"' exited with non-zero exit status 21: fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

**fdisk -l output:**

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   250069679   125034839+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/sdb: 240.1 GB, 240057409536 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 29185 cylinders, total 468862128 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4a839152

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048     1026047      512000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2         1026048   468858879   233916416    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2052474d

This doesn't look like a partition table
Probably you selected the wrong device.

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   ?     6579571  1924427647   958924038+  70  DiskSecure Multi-Boot
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sdc2   ?  1953251627  3771827541   909287957+  43  Unknown
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sdc3   ?   225735265   225735274           5   72  Unknown
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sdc4      2642411520  2642463409       25945    0  Empty

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdd: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdd doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sde: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2052474d

This doesn't look like a partition table
Probably you selected the wrong device.

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1   ?     6579571  1924427647   958924038+  70  DiskSecure Multi-Boot
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sde2   ?  1953251627  3771827541   909287957+  43  Unknown
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sde3   ?   225735265   225735274           5   72  Unknown
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sde4      2642411520  2642463409       25945    0  Empty

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_hhebdbabb_raid5vol1: 4000.8 GB, 4000792707072 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486402 cylinders, total 7814048256 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2052474d

This doesn't look like a partition table
Probably you selected the wrong device.

                               Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mapper/isw_hhebdbabb_raid5vol1p1   ?     6579571  1924427647   958924038+  70  DiskSecure Multi-Boot
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/mapper/isw_hhebdbabb_raid5vol1p2   ?  1953251627  3771827541   909287957+  43  Unknown
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/mapper/isw_hhebdbabb_raid5vol1p3   ?   225735265   225735274           5   72  Unknown
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/mapper/isw_hhebdbabb_raid5vol1p4      2642411520  2642463409       25945    0  Empty

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_hhebdbabb_raid5vol1p1: 981.9 GB, 981938215424 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 119380 cylinders, total 1917848077 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 262144 bytes
Alignment offset: 72192 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_hhebdbabb_raid5vol1p1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_hhebdbabb_raid5vol1p2: 931.1 GB, 931110868480 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 113201 cylinders, total 1818575915 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 262144 bytes
Alignment offset: 109056 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_hhebdbabb_raid5vol1p2 doesn't contain a valid partition table
fdisk: unable to read /dev/mapper/isw_hhebdbabb_raid5vol1p3: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

**dmraid -tay output:**

```
ERROR: ddf1: seeking device "/dev/dm-3" to 18446744073709425152
ERROR: hpt45x: seeking device "/dev/dm-3" to 18446744073709551104
ERROR: isw: seeking device "/dev/dm-3" to 18446744073708473856
ERROR: sil: seeking device "/dev/dm-3" to 18446744073709294080
isw_hhebdbabb_raid5vol1: 0 7814048256 raid raid5_la 4 256 nosync region_size 131072 3 - /dev/sdc - /dev/sdd - /dev/sde
isw_hhebdbabb_raid5vol1p1: 0 1917848077 linear /dev/mapper/isw_hhebdbabb_raid5vol1 6579571
isw_hhebdbabb_raid5vol1p2: 0 1818575915 linear /dev/mapper/isw_hhebdbabb_raid5vol1 1953251627
isw_hhebdbabb_raid5vol1p3: 0 10 linear /dev/mapper/isw_hhebdbabb_raid5vol1 225735265
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!